# Centering a variable based title that is positioned absolutely

Tags: css, variables, header

Alright so I have a page that's title always changes based on what person is logged in (their name is the title of the page). However because of the fact that the name is always going to be different that means that it needs to be positioned via the center of the text so that it will expand out horizontally both ways. I'm uncertain as to how to approach this and I have tried a few things however due to the variable length of the title none of the suggestions have panned out. So to give you the basics of where I'm at code wise:

```
#profteamName{
position:absolute;
text-align:center;
top:220px;
left: 550px;
color: white;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 1em blue, 0 0 0.2em darkblue;
text-decoration:underline;
```

I wouldn't be against using relative positioning. Just so long as it will expand horizontally.

(prefer to use absolute positioning long story there but I will take what I can get)

Thank you for your guys time.

Comment: And yes I am very new to the web design side of things, I much rather live in my c++ world lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than positioning the div from the left side of the page, stretch it across the entire window (or container div on the page) using `width:100%;`. It'll take up the entire width and align the text - regardless of the length - in the middle of the div.

**CSS**

```
.header {
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  top:50px;
  width:100%;  /* take the width of the window or container div */
  /* rest of your code */
}
```

Here's a **[CodePen mockup](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/MwpJGo)** you can play with.